# Enrolment functionality in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a e-course website where only the first course will be unlocked and the remaining courses will be locked. After user completes the first course, they will be required to take a quiz. If they pass the quiz with 75% or above, then only the following course will be unlocked. My code is below:

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
                   
                    @php
                      $enable_enroll = false;
                      $enrolled = false;
                      $user = backpack_user();
                      if($user)
                      {
                        $next = App\Models\Course::where('id', '<', $course->id)->max('id');
                        $previous = App\Models\Course::where('id', '>', $course->id)->max('id');
                        //  dd($next);
                        $enrollment = backpack_user()->enrollement;
                        if($course->id <= $next)
                        {
                          $enrolled = true;
                        }elseif($course->id >= $next){
                          $enable_enroll = true;
                        }

                        $lessons  =  App\Models\Lesson::all();

                        if($enrollment)
                        {
                            
                            foreach($enrollment as $key => $value)
                            {
                              
                              foreach($lessons as $lesson)
                              {
                                
                                if($lesson->course->id == $course->id)
                                {
                                  $enrolled = true;
                                }elseif($lesson->course->id > $course->id +1){
                                  $enrolled = false;
                                  $enable_enroll = true;
                                }else{
                                  $enrolled = false;
                                  $enable_enroll = false;
                              }
                              }
                            }
                        }
                        
                      }
                    @endphp
                    <div class="col max-mb-30" data-aos="fade-up">
                        <div class="course">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="{{url('course/'.$course->id)}}" class="image"><img src="{{asset($course->thumbnail)}}" alt="Course Image"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info">
                                <span class="price">{{$course->course_name}}</span><br>
                                
                                {{$course->short_description}}

                                @if(count($course->lessons)>1)
                                    <h3 class="title"><a href="{{url('lessons-grid/'.$course->id)}}">View Details</a></h3>
                                @else
                                    <h3 class="title"><a href="{{url('course/'.$course->id)}}">View Details</a></h3>
                                @endif



                                @if($enable_enroll)

                                    @if(count($course->lessons)>1)
                                  <h3 class="title"><a href="{{url('course/'.$course->id)}}">Enroll Now</a></h3></h3>
                                  @endif

                                @elseif($enrolled)
                                  Enrolled
                                @else
                                  
                                @endif

                                <ul class="meta">
                                    <li><i class="far fa-file-alt"></i>{{count($course->lessons)}} @if(count($course->lessons)>1) Lessons 
                                    @else
                                        Lesson
                                @endif</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{{$course->course_length}} min</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

It's not working. I need help.
Here are the screeshots of the database table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please post simplified version of your code to make it easier for others to understand and answer.

I don't know if this'll help but you can try this logic to get your desired result:

1. Store lesson id after user completes the lesson.
2. Get all the lessons in your course sorted in the their order in an array.
3. Check if the current lesson is before or after the last completed course in the array.
4. Unlock the course if current lesson is before or right after last course.

Good luck!